# How to update all job titles in active directory?

Tags: active-directory

What's the simplest way to export a list of all user accounts in a given AD OU, update their job titles, and then reimport them please?

Comment: Ahh.. "dsquery user -samid "User Name" | dsmod user -title "Network Monkey"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got access to the [Quest Active Directory PowerShell cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx), you can use the following commands.

`Get-QADUser | Select SamAccountName, Title | Export-Csv "JobTitles.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

This will export all your users and job titles to a CSV file in the current directory. Modify as required and then issue the following command to bring them back in.

`Import-Csv "JobTitles.csv" | ForEach{ Set-QADUser $_.SamAccountName -Title $_.Title }`

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I haven't right now but should be able to.  Tbh the comment I added about (embarrassingly) 2 minutes after asking the question details what appears to be a simple and workable solution so that will probably be first choice as it's idiot proof, so is a good match for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like WiseWoft Bulk Modify? http://www.activedir.org/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/66/Default.aspx

Comment: Interesting link thank you.  Problem here is some of the titles have comma's in them, which makes CSV files awkward to use directly.